# Trouble with positioning images evenly inside container

Tags: html, css, image

One of my questions about applying float to resizable images was answered by Gasim (thankyou) but I still have one more problem to fix.

I have two images which have this css code applied to them...

```
.image-container {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-image: url(Images/Filler2.png);
height: 250px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
.image-container {
    max-width: 500px;
}
}

.image-container2 {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-image: url(Images/Filler3.png);
height: 250px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
.image-container2 {
    max-width: 500px;
}
}
```

So now they're resizing correctly and aligned next to one another, I am unable to position them horizontally like my example below. I have tried the only way I know how to do this (margin-left: auto , margin-right:auto) but this didn't work. Also padding isn't working? Is there some part of this code which prevents these both from working and if so what do I need to fix it? 
Any input if helpful thanks :)

[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img912/981/MBjvwx.png]

Comment: so basically u dont want the second image to go down when resized

Comment: I do but that's once the page is too narrow it has to drop down. Like the image (resized example).

Comment: So u want it to move down

Comment: my trouble isn't moving it down, that seems easy once float is applied but my problem is applying the float to the id's, when I do so it makes the images disappear.

Comment: Can you explain why you have the `#BodyImage1::after`

Comment: I found a tutorial which showed me how to resize an image based on window size http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/entry.php?293-3-Ways-to-Resize-Scale-Web-Images-in-Responsive-Design
It's "Method #3 - Fluid Ratio Resize "
I'm still relatively knew to html so I can't explain why I need it sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not the best solution for responsive images, but I generally use media queries with a mobile first approach and it has been working out great. Basically, you set the boxes' widths to 100% by default and on larger screens you set the width that you want:

```
.image-container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: red; /* for testing */
    height: 250px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {
    .image-container {
        max-width: 500px;
    }
}
```

Here is the result: http://codepen.io/gasim/pen/xbYQdd

Try to make the window size smaller and you will see the difference. It is much simpler to test, debug, and modify this code.

EDIT: Forgot to mention. If you can also use `display: inline-block` instead of floats.

EDIT 2: To add padding between containers you need to add margin to a specific value, not auto. For example:

```
.image-container {
   /* rest of the values */
   margin: 5px;
}
```

This will add 5px margin to left, right, top, and bottom of the image container. If you want to have center the image containers also, I would add them in another container:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="image-container" style="background-image: url(URL_HERE);"></div>
   <div class="image-container" style="background-image: url(URL_HERE);"></div>
</div>
```

and add the styles:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 1224px) {
     .container {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
     }
 }
```

Also, please check out the way I added the background images, using styles. It is much cleaner than writing CSS for each background image. That way you can have one class `image-container` and just add as many background-images without relying on CSS.

Comment: Awesome thanks bud, with some small tweaking I managed to match the results to my previous code with my float (inline block) problem fixed :).
Now all I need to work out is the horizontal positioning of these images to match my example. Margin-left: auto, right-auto isn't doing anything, any ideas here? May as well ask the man himself :p

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Do you want to have two columns?

Comment: Do not put margin left and right auto. If you want this to be centered, put a container around the images with margin: 0 auto; I am on mobile right now but I'll update my answer when I 20mins.

Comment: Yeah for larger screen sizes basically identical to the image, but one with a smaller screen size. Its basically the spacing and alignment I'm having trouble with here.

Comment: Yeah think I'll wait the 20 minutes my images have disappear again :p

Comment: Thanks for everything, you gave me a solid foundation to build the correct code, needed a few adjustments for my layout but your method worked! :)